# Module import export issue

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I am trying to export a module, extend and export it in another module and then import it back in the original module in order to use it, like this:

```
// base-class.js
export class BaseClass {}

import { ExtendedBaseClass } from './extended-base-class.mjs';

console.log(ExtendedBaseClass);
```

```
// extended-base-class.js
import { BaseClass } from './base-class.mjs';

export class ExtendedBaseClass extends BaseClass {}
```

However it fails with an error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'BaseClass' before initialization, at extended-base-class.js:3:40
```

Based on my understanding of the order of operations this seem illogical, so what is the issue and how can I solve it?

For context: My current solution is to put just everything into the same file, but I want to move it into separate files, as my real classes are quite lengthy and thus I want to split it apart.

Comment: Try to put `module.exports = ...` before everything in both files.

Comment: You have a circular dependency between your modules. Either *base-class.js* runs first (in which case the imported `ExtendedBaseClass` will not be initialised when you log it) or *extendend-base-class.js* runs first (in which case the imported `BaseClass` will not be initialised when you `extends` it). The second is the issue that you observe. Solution: define and use them in the same module (in the proper order), or put the usage in a third module to avoid the circular dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ES6 modules always resolves their imports first before executing their body. So, in your case, base class will first try to import extended base class, even before exporting the base class from itself. Since extended base class tries to import base class first, it is not yet initialized at this point and hence you get the error.

What you can do is to move base class and extended base class to two separate files and then use a third file to import the extended base class

// base.js

```
export class BaseClass {}
```

// extended

```
import { BaseClass } from './base.js';
export class ExtendedBaseClass extends BaseClass {}
```

// index

```
import { ExtendedBaseClass } from './extended.js';
console.log(ExtendedBaseClass);
```

Alternatively, if you use CJS module system, your approach will work since the `require` statement which we use in CJS (equivalent of `import` here) works just similar to a normal function call. So it will only execute when the execution reaches that line. However it is very highly discouraged to have such circular dependencies since it could easily convolute the codebase

Comment: Even with CJS, circular dependencies like this are very annoying, hard to get right, and discouraged.

Comment: Can't agree more. Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. Using this way I was able to solve the issue!